# How to run cron job now and never run it again or run it every month?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I need to write a cron job to write a Python script, let's call it "script.py" and the command would be `python3 script.py`

Please note: It's a script that continuously runs and if I set it to rerun, it would spit out the script every time it would be scheduled like if I put it for every minute. I tried to schedule the cron job to run the script for every minute and that worked (but that's not what I want).

Is there a way to make it run "now", but never again or if not, to do it every month or so? I am so confused on how to do it.

For example today is May 8, 2020 and it is 7:21 PM. I want to start executing this cronjob now (next minute at 7:22 PM) and to never have the script execute again after that?

When I tried running it on the 8th of every month at 7:22 PM for example, the script did not work when it was 7:22 PM today.

How do I go about this?

Comment: You might want to look into `at(1)`. It may even already be installed on your system.Also see: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-schedule-tasks-using-at-command-on-linux

Comment: Hi. I am reviewing your post. Your question is good, but to help the community help you, it is always a good idea to add some code.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to run the job once, don't use `cron`; it has no way to achieve that.

If you want to run it at a later time, possibly after you've logged out, use [`at(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at).

If you want to run it after a short delay, like 1 minute in your example, and you plan to stay logged in (or the job makes itself a daemon), it may be simpler just to do `sleep 1m; myjob` in the shell.

If you want to run the job once a month, at 7:22pm on the 8th, you should be able to do

```
22 19 8 * * myjob
```

but note that the time is interpreted with respect to a global time zone, which may not match the time zone that you have set for yourself with the `TZ` environment variable.  According to https://askubuntu.com/questions/54364/how-do-you-set-the-timezone-for-crontab it should be the time zone specified by the file `/etc/localtime`.  If that's not the time zone you're expecting, then you can adjust the time specification in your `crontab` entry accordingly.